# OLAP that can handle Decimal Type

Tags: olap, olap-cube

Looking for an OLAP system to which will fit our current situation:

We have a 'report_data' MySQL table that has around 60 million rows. This table is used to store data from imported reports and it is mainly constructed out of FK(foreign key) and amount columns with all amount columns being of Decimal(32,20) type. There is also a waterfall model that is triggered every time a row is imported\updated and is used to aggregate data from the 'report_data' table to some 30 other smaller tables. These smaller aggregation tables are then used to feed imported report data to over 40 different charts\reports on the site.

The Web App itself is written in PHP with Symfony 4.4.

So for an OLAP system to be considered, it must satisfy these criteria:

- Can handle Decimal Types with up to 20 decimals with precision.
- Data from it can be fetched via RESTful API, so it can feed charts\reports on the site.
- Is open-source or comes at lowcost.
- Data to it can be streamed in (near)real-time.

Also, it would be preferable for OLAP to have a decent PHP client or Symfony bundle.

I have already tried Druid, which seemed promising until I figured out that it stores decimal values as float type because it does not support Decimal Type.

I'm very new to OLAP as a concept so any suggestions would be very helpful.